# Substitute to <iframe>

Tags: html, web, tags

I need to open a page inside another page without the horizontal scroll bar in the inner page.

I don't want to use `<iframe>` tags on my page. Is there any substitute to the `<iframe>` tag??

Comment: I beg your pardon ... you want to write HTML without HTML tags?

Comment: You could use <frameset> and <frame>... but it would be more interesting to know *why* you want to avoid <iframe>.

Comment: There are lots of problems people solve using iframes, and lots of other solutions to those problems - but those solutions don't apply to all the problems. What is the problem that you are currently solving with iframes?

Comment: @David
I need to open page without horizontal scroll bar.
Now any ideas...

Comment: @Martin...I want a replacement to the <iframe> tag....I never mentioned that I don't want HTML tags!!

Comment: Opening a page without a horizontal scrollbar is just a matter of including html,body { overflow-x: hidden; } in the stylesheet for the page. I don't see how an iframe could solve that problem in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is about the scrollbars (you mentioned that in your comment), you can hide/show them using stylesheets - try the following:

```
<body style="overflow-y:hidden; overflow-x:hidden">
...
</body>
```

You can use the styles on other tags (textareas etc.) as well.

PS: If you clarify your question, it's a good idea to edit the original post instead of commenting - this will make it easier to understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to avoid IFRAME is to use AJAX. If you would use jQuery it is as simple as that:

```
$('#yourDIV').load('http://someurl.com/example.html');
```

Where #yourDIV is ID of any element you want, DIV for example.

Comment: How is this better than <iframe>?

Comment: I wouldn't call a dependency on JavaScript the best way to get rid of iframes, and certainly not without context. We don't know if the same origin policy would cause a problem. We don't know if the goal is "Have scrollbars inside the page" rather than "Load content from another document".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `<object>` or `<embed>` or something like that.  I think you can put an html there.  But that would be sort of the same, i guess...

Comment: Sort of the same — just less well supported and less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate against `strict`, `<object>` should be the way to go.

```
<object data="example.html" type="text/html" width="500" height="300"></object>
```

Please note that MSIE 6 doesn't support html object tags.